# How to pair the str_detect and lag functions to look at more than one row at a time

Tags: r, lag

I already have functions to provide lag to one row. My problem is that I need to find the next instance (either before or after) where `strdetect=TRUE` if it's not in the immediate before or after. (eg: TRUE happens three rows up instead of one). I am using the following packages

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
```

This is the function I'm using to look behind one row:

```
#function to look behind one (
r_sen_from_states_alabama <- function(x){
  ifelse(str_detect(x, regex("the senator from Alabama",ignore_case = TRUE))==TRUE & str_detect(lag(x),"^Mr\\. SHELBY \\(R; Alabama\\):")==TRUE,
         str_replace(x,regex("the senator from Alabama", ignore_case = TRUE),"senator Shelby"),
         ifelse(str_detect(x, regex("the senator from Alabama", ignore_case = TRUE))==TRUE & str_detect(lag(x),"^Mr\\. SESSIONS \\(R; Alabama\\):")==TRUE,
                str_replace(x, regex("the senator from Alabama",ignore_case = TRUE), "senator Sessions"),x))
}
```

And this is the function I'm using to look ahead one row:

```
#function to look ahead one
r_sen_from_states_alabama <- function(x){
  ifelse(str_detect(x, regex("the senator from Alabama",ignore_case = TRUE))==TRUE & str_detect(lead(x),"^Mr\\. SHELBY \\(R; Alabama\\):")==TRUE,
         str_replace(x,regex("the senator from Alabama", ignore_case = TRUE),"senator Shelby"),
         ifelse(str_detect(x, regex("the senator from Alabama", ignore_case = TRUE))==TRUE & str_detect(lead(x),"^Mr\\. SESSIONS \\(R; Alabama\\):")==TRUE,
                str_replace(x, regex("the senator from Alabama",ignore_case = TRUE), "senator Sessions"),x))
}
test_df_try_1 <- as.data.frame(r_sen_from_states_alabama(test_df))
```

Here's some sample data for replication/debugging purposes.

```
#testing env data
test_col <- c("Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I acknowledge this is a test.",
              "Mrs. MURRAY (D; Washington): I say to my friend, the senator from Alabama, that they are wrong.",
              "Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I do not agree with my colleague.",
              "Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): The senator from Alabama is correct, senator Murray.",
              "Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I thank the majority leader for their support.",
              "Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): I am proud of my junior, the senator from Alabama.",
              "Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): To my senior peer, the senator from Alabama, I say great things.",
              "Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.",
              "Mr. Quail (Q; Nowhere): Match this one, the senator from Alabama, with the senator at the bottom.",
              "Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.",
              "Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space!",
              "Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space?",
              "Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): Match this one with Quail.")

test_df <- data.frame(test_col)
colnames(test_df) <- c("speeches")
```

Edited to include the expected output:

```
#Desired hypothetical results when using lag [note: 9 went lag(n = 2)
1   Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I acknowledge this is a test.
2   Mrs. MURRAY (D; Washington): I say to my friend, senator Shelby, that they are wrong.
3   Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I do not agree with my colleague.
4   Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): senator Shelby is correct, senator Murray.
5   Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I thank the majority leader for their support.
6   Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): I am proud of my junior, senator Shelby.
7   Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): To my senior peer, senator Sessions, I say great things.
8   Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.
9   Mr. Quail (Q; Nowhere): Match this one, senator Shelby, with the senator before.
10  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.
11  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space!
12  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space?
13  Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): Match this one with Quail.

#Desired hypothetical results when using lead [note: 6 went lead(n=7, 9 went lead(n=4)]
1  Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I acknowledge this is a test.
2  Mrs. MURRAY (D; Washington): I say to my friend, senator Shelby, that they are wrong.
3  Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I do not agree with my colleague.
4  Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): senator Shelby is correct, senator Murray.
5  Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I thank the majority leader for their support.
6  Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): I am proud of my junior, senator Shelby.
7  Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): To my senior peer, senator Sessions, I say great things.
8  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.
9  Mr. Quail (Q; Nowhere): Match this one, senator Sessions, with the senator at the bottom.
10 Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.
11 Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space!
12 Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space?
13 Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): Match this one with Quail.
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: what exactly do you want as your FINAL output?. So far all these questions you are asking are intermediate problems and the way you are tackling the problem is most definitely inefficient oe even incorrect

Comment: @Onyambu Ultimately, the FINAL output will be a dataframe with rows where one senator is speaking about another. I need to convert third person references by one senator about another so that I can run sentiment analysis on the statements. This is going to be done across 2 years (the 108th Congress).

Comment: @r2evans sorry for the oversight, I just edited the post to include the desired hypothetical output if I can set the n in lag/lead to more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach. I used `case_when`. Can you confirm that this is what you're looking for?

I used `any` to look at both lag and lead at the same time. I also looked for the senator's name in the current line, to prevent that senator from referring to themselves. (This is negated.)

However, this essentially uses your code, just arranged a bit differently. Let me know if you have any questions. (I don't think I need to explain *your* code... but if anything is unclear or if you're unfamiliar with `case_when`, I am happy to explain.)

```
tdf = test_df %>% 
  mutate(tellMe = case_when(
    str_detect(speeches, regex("senator from Alabama", ignore_case = T)) & 
      str_detect(speeches, regex("SHELBY \\(R; Alabama\\)", ignore_case = T), negate = T) &
      any(str_detect(lag(speeches), "SHELBY \\(R; Alabama\\)"),
          str_detect(lead(speeches), "SHELBY \\(R; Alabama\\)")) ~
      str_replace(speeches, regex("the senator from Alabama", ignore_case = T),
                  "senator Shelby"),
    str_detect(speeches, regex("senator from Alabama", ignore_case = T)) & 
      str_detect(speeches, regex("SESSIONS \\(R; Alabama\\)", ignore_case = T), negate = T) &
      any(str_detect(lag(speeches), "SESSIONS \\(R; Alabama\\)"),
          str_detect(lead(speeches), "SESSIONS \\(R; Alabama\\)")) ~
      str_replace(speeches, regex("the senator from Alabama", ignore_case = T),
                  "senator Sessions"),
    TRUE ~ speeches
  ))

1                                   Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I acknowledge this is a test.
2    Mrs. MURRAY (D; Washington): I say to my friend, senator Shelby, that they are wrong.
3                               Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I do not agree with my colleague.
4                     Mr. FRIST (R; Tennessee): senator Shelby is correct, senator Murray.
5                  Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): I thank the majority leader for their support.
6                      Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): I am proud of my junior, senator Shelby.
7        Mr. SHELBY (R; Alabama): To my senior peer, senator Sessions, I say great things.
8                                   Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.
9  Mr. Quail (Q; Nowhere): Match this one, senator Shelby, with the senator at the bottom.
10                                  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space.
11                                  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space!
12                                  Ms. PEABODY (I; Atlantis): This is just to fill space?
13                                   Mr. SESSIONS (R; Alabama): Match this one with Quail.
>
```